# What is a Counterfeiting Word™?

Tags: english, word-property

This puzzle is in the spirit of the What is a Word/Phrase™ series started by [JLee](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/463/jlee) with a special brand of [Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22Phrase%22+is%3Aquestion) and [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22What+is+a%22+%22Word%22+-missing+is%3Aquestion) puzzles.

---

If a word conforms to a special rule I call it a Counterfeiting word™. Here are some examples of Counterfeiting word™ and not Counterfeiting word™:

```
+----------------------+--------------------------+
| Counterfeiting Word™ | not Counterfeiting Word™ |
+----------------------+--------------------------+
| push                 | first                    |
| fast                 | strong                   |
| noisy                | light                    |
| defend               | against                  |
| old                  | floor                    |
| adult                | refuse                   |
| wet                  | wide                     |
| major                | exit                     |
| wrong                | correct                  |
| export               | buy                      |
| below                | optimistic               |
| failure              | all                      |
| lose                 | girl                     |
| soft                 | expensive                |
| include              | hot                      |
| senior               | ascent                   |
| permit               | happy                    |
+----------------------+--------------------------+
```

And a CSV version for copy-paste purpose:

```
Counterfeiting Word™,not Counterfeiting Word™
push,first
fast,strong
noisy,light
defend,against
old,floor
adult,refuse
wet,wide
major,exit
wrong,correct
export,buy
below,optimistic
failure,all
lose,girl
soft,expensive
include,hot
senior,ascent
permit,happy
```

You can check whether a word is a Counterfeiting word™ or not without looking at the words in its column. These are not the only Counterfeiting words™: many more exist.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A Counterfeiting Word™ is...

> one where the opposite has the same number of letters.
>  `PUSH/PULL`;`FAST/SLOW`;`NOISY/QUIET`;`DEFEND/ATTACK`;`OLD/NEW`;`ADULT/CHILD`;`WET/DRY`;`MAJOR/MINOR`;`WRONG/RIGHT`;`EXPORT/IMPORT`;`BELOW/ABOVE`;`FAILURE/SUCCESS`;`LOSE/GAIN`;`SOFT/HARD`;`INCLUDE/EXCLUDE`;`SENIOR/JUNIOR`;`PERMIT/FORBID`.
>
>  There are no opposites to the right-hand words that have the same number of letters; each has a different number of letters as its opposite. (`FIRST/LAST`; `STRONG/WEAK`; etc)

Comment: I like the answer, but what about rot13(yvtug/urnil)?  There are other reasonable counterexamples, too, like rot13(svefg/svany naq ershfr/npprcg).  Is there some concept of a rot13("eryrinag" bccbfvgr) to use here?

Comment: @mbingo Yeah, I'm not entirely happy with this either -- it seems like some of them are ambiguous. But at the same time, it seems right -- maybe there's some other constraint I'm missing?

Comment: Yeah—your list is solid, and rot13("pbhagresrvg" = pbhagre-svg, v.r. bccbfvgrf... gung svg) is appropriate.

Comment: That's the right answer indeed. @mbingo you are right about the definition. I was thinking at: rot13(yvtug/qnex), rot13(svefg/ynfg) and rot13(ershfr/nccebir). But also rot13(ybfr/svaq) so yes, some of them are definitely ambiguous